# How to Deploy MEAN stack to my hosted server?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, hosting, mean-stack, mean.io

I have a great working website built with MEAN and works great locally.
i wish to deploy it on my server, 
but i never deployed a website 
other than uploading the files to my website ftp.

Tutorials anyone?

Comment: It is going to be difficult if you don´t have a web server with root access. If you do, log onto your server, install (M)ongoDB, (E)xpress.js, (A)ngular and (N)ode.js, upload your files to the server, navigate to destination directory and execute.

Comment: You need a server with shell access or a hosted Node.js service such as Heroku. After that it's as simple as installing node (if you have shell access), installing your dependencies and running it.

Comment: I am also trying to learn this myself, and found this tutorial http://justinklemm.com/grunt-js-deployment-ssh-git/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from here...
https://github.com/linnovate/mean#hosting-mean
What operating system do you plan to host it on?

Comment: Outdated link/answer

Answer (score 2):

Another good starting point would be Digital Ocean, they offer a one click install MEAN stack, with tutorials. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-mean-one-click-install-image

Answer (score 2):

I have just deployed my `MEAN Stack application` on `Heroku cloud application` environment. The deployment steps are easy.

**Steps to deploy:**

1. Your mean stack project structure should be like [this](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist-angular2). `This is very important step. The bottonline is your package.json and server.js should be under your root directory. Have a look at the link to know more about the structure.`
2. Clone your remote repository locally i.e. `git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git`
3. Go inside the cloned repository e.g. `cd node-js-getting-started`
4. Run `git add .`
5. Run `git commit -m "Sample"`
6. Run `Heroku login` (It will ask you to press any key and then open up the browser and ask you to click login. After logged in closed the browser instance.
7. Run `heroku create myApp --buildpack heroku/nodejs`. `Note: Buildpacks are responsible for transforming deployed code into a slug, which can then be executed on a dyno`. [More information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)
8. Run `git push heroku master`. Your deplyment will start.
9. Once deployment is done, you will see the complete deployment logs on command prompt terminal
10. The application is now deployed. Ensure that at least one instance of the app is running: `heroku ps:scale web=1`
11. Run `heroku open`. It will run your deployed instance.
12. Run `heroku logs` to view information about your running app. [More information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#view-logs)

You can find more details visiting following links:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prepare-the-app
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs